# ResolutionPath for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linq, f#

I'm new to F#. I'm running the following sample code found on 
http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/:

```
// reference the type provider dll
#r "FSharp.Data.SQLProvider.dll"
open System
open System.Linq
open FSharp.Data.Sql

// create a type alias with the connection string and database vendor settings
type sql = SqlDataProvider< 
              ConnectionString = @"Data Source=F:\sqlite\northwindEF.db ;Version=3",
              DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.SQLITE,
              ResolutionPath = @"F:\sqlite\3",
              IndividualsAmount = 1000,
              UseOptionTypes = true >
let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()

// pick individual entities from the database 
let christina = ctx.``[main].[Customers]``.Individuals.``As ContactName``.``BERGS, Christina Berglund``

// directly enumerate an entity's relationships, 
// this creates and triggers the relevant query in the background
let christinasOrders = christina.FK_Orders_0_0 |> Seq.toArray

let mattisOrderDetails =
    query { for c in ctx.``[main].[Customers]`` do
            // you can directly enumerate relationships with no join information
            for o in c.FK_Orders_0_0 do
            // or you can explicitly join on the fields you choose
            join od in ctx.``[main].[OrderDetails]`` on (o.OrderID = od.OrderID)
            //  the (!!) operator will perform an outer join on a relationship
            for prod in (!!) od.FK_OrderDetails_0_0 do 
            // nullable columns can be represented as option types. The following generates IS NOT NULL
            where c.CompanyName.IsSome                
            // standard operators will work as expected; the following shows the like operator and IN operator
            where (c.ContactName =% ("Matti%") && o.ShipCountry |=| [|"Finland";"England"|] )
            sortBy o.ShipName
            // arbitrarily complex projections are supported
            select (c.ContactName,o.ShipAddress,o.ShipCountry,prod.ProductName,prod.UnitPrice) } 
    |> Seq.toArray
```

However, I'm targeting SQL Server and not SQLite. I therefore need to modify the connection string and vendor initialisation.

The problem, is that I am not familiar with this and struggling to correctly find what to use as a "ResolutionPath" for SQL Server.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your [link](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/) (and my personal experience) the `ResolutionPath` parameter isn't needed for SQL Server:

> All database vendors except SQL Server and MS Access [...] You must supply the location of the assemblies with the "ResolutionPath" static parameter.